# Merging Musar and Mussar tags

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-tag

Can a Moderator please merge the [musar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musar) tag into the [mussar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mussar) tag? I created the former not realizing the latter existed.

Answer (score 1):

I have merged these two tags.

In this case, you could have just edited the question to use the main tag instead, and the system would eventually expunge the new tag for having no members.

Comment: But this way we have more synonyms.

Comment: More importantly, why are we using the double 's' one? מוסר doesn't have a dagesh in the samech.

Comment: For an early participant in Mi.yodyea, I feel a little out of the know on some of this stuff.